# A command for making a string of characters

Tags: macros, characters, strings

How can I make a command (or is there an existing one?) which takes two arguments: 1) character type 2) N (count) and puts N number of characters side by side?

```
\newcommand{\foo}[2]
{
    % sample: \foo{c}{3} -> ccc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\newcommand{\stringnumber}[2]{%
    \ifnum #2>0
        #1%
        \stringnumber{#1}{\numexpr#2-1}
    \fi
}
```

---

The previous code, when the number of requested repetitions is high, generates very long token lists. Here's a better implementation that avoids the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

% it's better if the number of repetitions is first
\newcommand{\stringnumber}[2]{\dostringnumber{#2}{#1}}
\makeatletter
% call \dostringnumber recursively
\newcommand{\dostringnumber}[2]{%
  \ifnum #1>0
    % produce the second argument
    #2%
    % generate the next call; the last \expandafter gets rid of \else
    \expandafter\dostringnumber\expandafter{\number\numexpr#1-1\expandafter}%
  \else
    % get rid of the text in case we are at the end of the recursion
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \fi
  {#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

X\stringnumber{Ok!}{7}X\stringnumber{Ok!}{1}X\stringnumber{Ok!}{0}X

\end{document}
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind for the remarks I added.

Comment: I don't, in my own interest I prefer when better content is shown. So thank you.

Comment: @egreg BTW why did you put a `\number` there?

Comment: This expands `\numexpr#1-1` to an explicit number and also has the effect of triggering `\expandafter` which gets rid of `\else` up to and including `\fi`. So the next `\dostringnumber` is executed *outside* any conditional. The problems with your code are that a `-1` is added for each iteration and conditionals heap up.